# Simple bash script does not want to start at reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, java, apache2, scripts

I've build a Play Framework Application (cool Java/Scala Web Framework) and would like to start it automatically like Apache2 or MySQL Server. For this I wrote a simple Bash script and did `chmod +x` on it, put it in `/etc/init.d/` and it works fine when I call it manually in the shell. The Bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/cc/Desktop/java/playmulti/playstart
```

This calls the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
(play start &)
```

The `play start` starts the Play Framework Application in `/home/cc/Desktop/java/playmulti/`. Also I did `ls -s` and tried to  put in different `/etc/rcX.d/` directories. I even used `update-rc.d` to put it there, but nothing I try seems to work. Script doesn't start with the reboot :/

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the exact sequence of commands that you used? Specifically, how did you use update-rc.d?

Comment: To start the script in "/home/cc/Desktop/java/playmulti/playstart" I did: "./playstart". To start "update-rc.d" I did "update-rc.d playmulti defaults" in the same directory. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I should mention that I got the standard result from update-rc.d as shown here: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28

Comment: Have you considered that during boot time you will only have a restricted environment set up? If your application framework requires e.g. a `JAVA_HOME` setting this may not be available yet.

Comment: @MarcusRickert That could be. Also Play somehow demands on my Debian Deployment Server to run as "root". Thank you very much! Do you have a suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Well, one way to do this is is to source your bashrc script using the dot notation, e.g. `. ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of your script. The best way strongly depends on your specific setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think your sh file not geting its environment to run the scrip when start up
you can do
first go to your file path by

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> cd /home/cc/Desktop/java/playmulti
> java -cp your jar files along your full class path

Comment: That's correct! I had to "cd" into the folder and also to call the the full path for the "play" command, like "/folder/of/framework/play start". Thanks!

Comment: you are well come